# Override certain attributes of a custom control

Tags: android, android-library, android-styles

Let's say there's a custom control and related style in an Android library project. The application that uses this library wants to override certain attributes of that control, while inheriting the others. In my current approach, I have the following code:

In library/styles.xml:

```
<style name="CreditCardInputField">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/border</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
</style>
```

In app/styles.xml:

```
<style name="CreditCardInputField">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">50dp</item>
</style>
```

The result I have is that the style from the app completely overrides the style from the library. I.e. I lose the `background` and `textStyle` properties, while correctly overriding the `layout_margin`. This is not what I want, I want to keep the `background` and `textStyle` as they're defined in library. Is it possible, and, if yes, how?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I don't want to use the style directly in the app, only the custom control from the library that uses the style. Therefore creating a new style in the app (with a parent from the library) does effectively nothing.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? what does **only the custom control from the library that uses the style** mean?

Comment: Sure. My goal is to create a setup where library can provide a custom control, and the application can customise that control to a certain extent. I was thinking about different approaches, including custom attributes via `<declare-styleable>` and overriding styles. Apparently, styles don't work well in this setup.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible and as far as my understanding, when you created  the style `CreditCardInputField` it worked that way because it was not overriding a particular  attribute but it was overwriting the full style. The style in libs/style was not visible to the application due to same name.

(something similar to scope in any other programming language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to achieve what I want through the custom attributes. Not as convenient as with a style, but more flexible. In short, declare custom attributes in the library, read them in the control's code, provide in the app. Here's the almost complete code, maybe this will help someone:

In lib/values/attrs.xml (custom attributes are declared here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="test_view">
        <attr name="field_margins" format="dimension">50dp</attr>
        <attr name="field_background" format="reference">@drawable/border</attr>
        <attr name="name_field_hint" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="number_field_hint" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In lib/layout/credit_card_view.xml (this is the custom control's layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditText
        style="@style/CreditCardInputField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        style="@style/CreditCardInputField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</merge>
```

In lib/java/TestView.java (the custom control itself):

```
public class TestView extends LinearLayout {
    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.test_view, 0, 0);
        int margins = (int)a.getDimension(R.styleable.test_view_field_margins, 0f);
        int background = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.test_view_field_background, R.drawable.border);
        int nameFieldHint = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.test_view_name_field_hint, R.string.name_field_hint_lib);
        int numberFieldHint = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.test_view_number_field_hint, R.string.number_field_hint_lib);
        a.recycle();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.credit_card_view, this, true);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        TextView title = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
        title.setHint(nameFieldHint);
        title.setBackgroundResource(background);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(context, attrs);
        p.setMargins(margins, margins, margins, margins);
        title.setLayoutParams(p);

        TextView number = (TextView) getChildAt(1);
        number.setHint(numberFieldHint);
        number.setBackgroundResource(background);
        number.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
}
```

And finally in app/layout/main_activity.xml, custom control's usage and configuration:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...>

<com.example.testlibrary.TestView
    custom:field_margins="20dp"
    custom:field_background="@drawable/field_background"
    custom:name_field_hint="@string/name_field_hint"
    custom:number_field_hint="@string/number_field_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different name to your style in app/styles.xml and make the other style as it's parent.

```
<style name="newCreditCardInputField" parent="CreditCardInputField">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">50dp</item>
</style>
```

This will override your layout_margin while restoring background and textStyle.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parent [attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) e.g.:

```
<style name="CreditCardInputField" parent="parentStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/border</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
</style>
```