# Z-index in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, z-index, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/basketLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basketItemnumber"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/basket_item_number"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/marginSpacer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/shoppingBasketButton"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:id="@+id/marginSpacer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shoppingBasketButton"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/shoppingBasketButton"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/shoppingBasketButton" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/shoppingBasketButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now the `shoppingBasketButton` is overlapping the `basketItemnumber` but I want to have it the other way round.

But I could not figure out how to change the z-index of the items.

I tried `setTranslationZ` and `setZ` but wasn't successful.

`bringToFront()` also didn't work for me.

**Edit:**
I managed to get it working with:

```
ViewCompat.setZ(basketItemnumber, 999);
basketItemnumber.invalidate();
```

But I couldn't manage to do this for API < 21.

**Edit:**
I also tried already to change the order of my views. This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you can put your basketItemnumber after shoppingBasketButton and it can resolve your problem.

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/basketLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/marginSpacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shoppingBasketButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/shoppingBasketButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/shoppingBasketButton" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/shoppingBasketButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="auto"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basketItemnumber"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/basket_item_number"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/marginSpacer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/shoppingBasketButton"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: there was already another answer proposing the same, but I already tried this and it did not work.

Comment: in my case it works, i can show the printscreen. What is the root layout and other xml code in your case?

Comment: It works when I am not using a floatingActionButton and a TextView or something like this instead.

Comment: So what is yours root layout? i tried my code in studio with floatingActionButton and a TextView and it works.

Comment: Problem is, that it is very big. My constraintLayout is in a RelativeLayout which is in a LinearLayout which is in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Okay, I created a testfile where I only have the code I posted here. And still it doesn't show me the right z-order in my preview in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Add `android:elevation="6dp"` to your text view

Comment: And put text view after FloatingActionButton

Comment: With elevation it works. But I have 16 mindSDK and elevation just works with 21 or higher.

Comment: did you tried also `bringChildToFront` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#bringChildToFront(android.view.View)

Comment: maybe you can try to override `FloatingActionButton_elevation` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31203867/7917629. but I dont know what result you will get.

Comment: I fixed it by doing this: `ViewCompat.setElevation(basketItemnumber, 6);`
Maybe you can add this to your answer somehow?